# How to print an equilateral Triangle in C using 1 loop?

Tags: c, printf

I want to print the sequence *********** in equilateral form

for given input n(here 5) using a single loop in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

I tried it using the normal method where I use one outer loop and one inner loop to print the corresponding elements. Now, my aim is to reduce the time complexity by making the use of 1 loop.

```
for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n-i;j++)
    printf(" ");

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("* ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Using one loop does not decrease time complexity..

Comment: Please be careful when editing your questions, so you don't remove other peoples edits (unless it's a faulty edit).

Comment: @Udit Gavasane Show the form of the triangle you are going to output.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, rows;

    /* Input number of rows to print */
    printf("Enter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    /* Iterate through rows */
    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    { 
        /* Print leading spaces */
        for(j=i; j<rows; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        /* Print star */
        for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        /* Move to next line */
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter number of rows: 5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Comment: That's really not that different from the loops the OP already have. The OP want only a *single* loop, not nested loops.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is not happen with a single loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use an unreadable single loop (testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/22ZS8qqJY28JLlil)).

```
void print_triangle(int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
        return;

    int m = n * n;
    for (int i = 0, e = n - 1, f = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        if ( i >= f )
           putchar('*');
        if ( i != e )
            putchar(' ');
        else
        {
            putchar('\n');
            f += n + 1;
            e += n;
        }
    }
}
```

Whether it is worth the pain or not is questionable. I'd say no.